# Cartthrob display fields only if shipping or tax has a value greater than $0.00

Tags: cartthrob

Working on our new Cartthrob install, I want to hide the shipping and tax fields on both the cart page and the checkout page if either the shipping or tax are $0.00...

I tried this for shipping:

```
{if exp:cartthrob:cart_shipping != "$0.00"}
    <tr>
      <td>
        Shipping
      </td>
      <td>
      {exp:cartthrob:cart_shipping}
      </td>
   </tr>
   {/if}
```

But doesn't seem to do what I want... Any suggestions or maybe I'm just not using the tag correctly?

Comment: Does  {exp:carttrhob:cart_shipping} output with the prepended dollar sign?

Comment: yep, it outputs $0.00.. I've tried both as well "0.00" and "$0.00".

Answer (score 0):

OK - after futzing around a bit I got something that works for what I want.

```
       {if {exp:cartthrob:cart_shipping prefix="" decimals="0"} != 0}

       YES 

       {if:else}

       NO

       {/if}
```